# Read "OS install date" value from registry with RegQueryValueExA() api failed

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I wanna read **`Windows Install Date`** value from *registry* using Windows API as bellow :

```
HKEY hKey = { 0 };
LONG lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;

// Open a registry key
lResult = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion",
                        0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

// If registry key opened
if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // Get OS install date/time
    DWORD dwInstallDate = 0;
    dwBufferSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    if (RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "InstallDate", 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)&dwInstallDate, &dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("OS Install Date is : %lu", dwInstallDate);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The specific key not found!");
    }

    // Finally we should close the key when we finished with it
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

But the output is always `0`, while `"InstallDate"` value is `1520291827`:

```
OS Installe Date is : 0
```

Also, I'm used of `"%ld"` and `"d"` formats, but it has the same output...
The "InstallDate" value in registry, contained a `REG_DWORD` type.
By the way, when i create a new `REG_DWORD` value, my code cannot read it :

For example , I create a value in bellow reg-address as `"test"` with `123` data :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

But `dwInstallDate` will be `0` instead of `123` :

```
RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "test", 0,
                 NULL, (LPBYTE)&dwInstallDate,
                 &dwBufferSize);
```

Any Suggestion? I'm confused about this action...

Comment: A `DWORD` is not a `long`. Cast it in the printf statement.

Comment: Question has been asked a bazillion times. See [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) to learn about the underlying issue. Once you find the appropriate duplicate, you can close this question.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks... you gave me a clue, i changed my solution platform to `x64` and its worked... why is this ok in `x64`?

Comment: you can do this in 32 bit app too, if use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_READ` look for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion@InstallDate` - here really 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***According Microsoft :***

- `KEY_WOW64_32KEY (0x0200)` :

  Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 32-bit registry view. This flag is ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa384129).
  This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags in this table that either query or access registry values.
  Windows 2000: This flag is not supported.
- `KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)` :

  Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 64-bit registry view. This flag is ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa384129).
  This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags in this table that either query or access registry values.
  Windows 2000: This flag is not supported.

I used of `KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_READ` either way `x86` and `x64` :

```
// Open a registry key
lResult = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion",
                        0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_READ, &hKey);
```

It does work.